# how to install new packages with python 3.1.1?

Tags: python

I've tried to install pip on windows, but it's not working:

giving me ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

easy_install doesn't have version 3.1 or so, just 2.5, and should be replaced by pim.

is there easy way to install it on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setuptools doesn't quite work on Python 3.1 yet. Try installing packages with regular distutils, or use binary packages (.exe, .msi) provided by the package author.

Comment: depends on what specific packages you need. 2.5 is not maintained anymore, so if you use 2.x, use 2.6.